# Is $\prod_{i\in I}x_i$ equal to $1-\prod_{i\in I}(1-x_i)$?

Tags: products

Are these 2 equations equivalent? If so how can I prove it, if not how can I disprove it?

$CI(t)=\prod_{t_i<t}(d_i/n_i)$

$CI(t)=1-\prod_{t_i<t}(1-(d_i/n_i))$

Comment: $ab \neq 1-(1-a)(1-b)$ in general

Comment: [Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35391/quick-beginner-guide-for-asking-a-well-received-question) + please [avoid "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933) (don't just ask, do some work), and don't use [the tag proof-writing](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/proof-writing) to ask for a proof. And use a more descriptive title, and include the question in the body of the post.

Comment: Could you please delete the question? I can't unfortunately. @AnneBauval

Comment: [You cannot](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-questions) because it has an upvoted or accepted answer. Neither can I vote for its deletion because there is no Delete button yet on the line below it. I was only able to vote for its closure.

Answer (score 2):

Just try it:

$$ab \stackrel{?}{=} 1 - (1-a) \cdot (1-b)$$

Well:
$1 - (1-a) \cdot (1-b) = 1 - (1 - a - b + ab) = a + b - ab \ne ab$

So, no. Those equations are not equal.

Comment: This question does not meet the [standards for the site](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question). Instead of answering
 (which encourages low-quality questions), why not look for a good duplicate target, or help the user by posting comments suggesting improvements? Please also read the [meta announcement](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards) regarding quality standards.